# Parent Drop Down Menu Needs A Transition Relative To The Amount Of Child Options

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

Forgive me for the poor explanation in the title, I am stuggling to describe the issue.  Please view http://www.lexiconnect.net/websites/sandyx.

If you hover each menu item you will see that some categories have more items under them than others.  I am wanting the Drop Down Menu to extend to a height relative to the amount of category items under that category.

For example, if you hover over 'About Us', there are 3 items and a huge amount of space under it.  Whereas if you hover over 'Products and Services' you will see 6 items with the ***CORRECT*** amount of space underneath them.

Here is the styling to the drop down menu:-

```
    #menu .menuaholder:hover .menudropdownh {
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    -ms-transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    -o-transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;`enter code here`
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    visibility: visible;
    height: 580px;
    border-top: 10px solid #e60030;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /* Safari */
    transition-delay: 1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 1s;
    }

    #menu .menudropdownh {
    position:absolute;
    width: 1200px;
    left:-290px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    -ms-transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    -o-transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    z-index: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0 -500px 0 -500px;
    padding: 0 500px 0 500px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #3c99d5; /* Old browsers */
    background: url(../images/cloud-texture.png) repeat-x 0 100%, -moz-linear-    gradient(top,  #3c99d5 0%, #a5c9e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: url(../images/cloud-texture.png) repeat-x 0 100%, -webkit- gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3c99d5), color- stop(100%,#a5c9e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: url(../images/cloud-texture.png) repeat-x 0 100%, -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #3c99d5 0%,#a5c9e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: url(../images/cloud-texture.png) repeat-x 0 100%, -o-linear-gradient(top,  #3c99d5 0%,#a5c9e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:  url(../images/cloud-texture.png) repeat-x 0 100%, -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #3c99d5 0%,#a5c9e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: url(../images/cloud-texture.png) repeat-x 0 100%, linear-gradient(to bottom,  #3c99d5 0%,#a5c9e5 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3c99d5', endColorstr='#a5c9e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }
```

I have removed the heights on both selectors which did not work.  I then placed height:100%; on there which did not work.

The closest I got to was placing was placing 'overflow: visible' but the background would not extend on hover.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: better use `height:100%!important` hope it works or `height:auto`

Comment: @Amitsingh `!important` is rarely ever the solution and often causes more problems than it fixes.

Comment: did you use `height:auto`

Comment: You'd need javascript to do that. CSS can't detect content or the number of things like you suggest. Alternatively, try using `max-height`...it might get you closer.

Comment: @Amitsingh - Thanks, this works best at the moment and does achieve the result I am looking for, it is just stops the smooth transition as it extends.  I will look into this further and post what I find here.  Thanks for all your help guys.